# Convert an avi file (IV50 codec) to a Quicktime file

Tags: macos, video, conversion, iv50

I found this old CD of video clips that are all .avi files, I've found out the codec is IV50 (Indeo v5). They won't open in VLC in Mac OS X but do open in WMP9 on my Windows machine. Does anyone know of a converter program that supports converting from IV50 to some usable Quicktime format (hopefully MPEG4)?

**UPDATE**: Thanks for the answers, I looked into ffmpeg and it looks like it will be useful in the future if I need to do anything else with video. The solution I ended up going with was importing the clips into, of all things, Windows Movie Maker and exporting with a usable codec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and MEncoder (comes with [Mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html)) are probably the two most comprehensive video conversion/decoding/encoding tools available. I'd suggest giving them a try.

I think MEncoder *may* utilise codecs on the system [not certain about this], so I would try doing the conversion on a windows PC that is capable of playing them as that way you know you have a valid codec for the format.

Comment: ffmpeg does not use the codecs in the OS, and I know from previous experience it doesn't support IV50. Not sure about mencoder though.

Comment: @Badaro: Thanks, I've updated with your new info. Post back if you get it working so we can come up with a definitive answer for future reference.

Comment: YMMV, but I did a quick test, and while mplayer/mencoder can play the file using the installed DirectShow codec, my attempts to convert an IV50 file to another format using it resulted in a corrupted file.

Comment: I would guess that if MPlayer can play the file it is almost certainly possible to convert it. What command line are you using?

Comment: It converts the file but the output doesn't play properly. Here's a commandline I tested: mencoder -oac lavc -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=300:vpass=1 output_xvid.avi -o sample_teste.avi

Comment: Looks like it should work. Do you need to do a second pass?

Answer (score 1):

Try this website and click on convert tab on the left side.... and select your avi file and then choose a output formate "mov" which is a Quicktime media file format.... hope this tip  will be working for you...
[Freefileconvert](http://www.freefileconvert.com)

Answer (score 0):

While [meGUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/) is not the most user-friendly tool around, it's an amazing converter with high-quality presets for MP4. Also, since it uses [AviSynth](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page) for input, anything that plays in WMP will work on it.