# Error playing a video: VLC does not support the audio or video format "IV50"

Tags: codec, iv50

I have used every step mentioned in the below given link:

http://www.moviecodec.com/solutions/iv31-iv32-iv41-iv50-indeo-3-4-and-5-8211/

installed older version on quick-time, window media player classic. I mean everything. But still no luck running the file.

I was also trying to find a converter to convert the file into an acceptable format. But unable to do that either.

Can anyone help me with this.

Regards
Zeeshan

Comment: I think this question is more suited to SuperUser.
Also, have you tried it on a different computer if you have another one available?

Answer (score 3):

IV50 is [Indeo Video 5.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeo), originally created by Intel then sold to Ligos.

Try a combination off [ffdshow tryouts](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) for codec and [Media Player Classic Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) as player.

**EDIT**: from the Wikipedia article:

> Indeo is not supported and is not
>   compatible with Microsoft Windows
>   Vista, Windows 7 or any Windows 64-bit
>   operating system

Which OS are you using?

Comment: Wikipedia link above suggests that indeo support can be enabled on latest Windows versions with `regsvr32 ir50_32.dll` command. And it worked on my Windows 7 x64! But beware of Security advisory on the same link as codec is intentionally disabled due to known vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3):

[mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) can handle playback of IV50. Download the version that includes SMPlayer for a decent windows interface.

Transcoding (if needed) could be handled by the included mencoder which can be done by a command line like:
`mencoder <filename.avi> -ovc xvid -oac mp3lame -xvidencopts bitrate=687 -o <output.avi>`. Which would convert it to an avi file encoding with xvid.

Comment: this old question indicates *ffmpeg* can transcode *iv50* as well: http://superuser.com/questions/11776/convert-an-avi-file-iv50-codec-to-a-quicktime-file